# Query a table with 2 foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, union

I've this 4 tables.

```
Mail
----
id
date

Source (can have many source)
------
id
mailID : FK Mail.id
personID : FK Person.id

Destination  (can have many destination)
-----------
id 
mailID : FK Mail.id
personID : FK Person.id

Person
------
id
name
```

I'm trying to create a query that returns every mail with all the source and destination ids.

So far I've come out with this query, but it's rather inefficient as it queries the same table twice.

```
Select * FROM (
    Select m.*, personID, 'Source' AS TableName
    FROM Mail m join Source s 
    ON m.id = s.mailid
UNION ALL
    Select m.*, personID, 'Destination' AS TableName 
    FROM Mail m join Destination d
    ON m.id = d.mailid


) t ORDER BY id, TableName;

results:

id | date | personID | TableName
--------------------------------
 1 | 1-1-11| 3       | Source
 1 | 1-1-11| 4       | Source
 1 | 1-1-11| 5       | Source
 1 | 1-1-11| 10      | Destination
 1 | 1-1-11| 11      | Destination
 2 | 2-2-11| 1       | Source
 2 | 2-2-11| 2       | Destination
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, a.personID, a.TableName
FROM Mail m
INNER JOIN (SELECT s.mailid, s.personID, 'Source' AS TableName
            FROM Source s 
           UNION ALL
            SELECT d.mailid, d.personID, 'Destination' AS TableName
            FROM Destination d
           ) AS a ON m.id = a.mailid
ORDER BY m.id, a.TableName;
```

Comment: Totally forgot I could just move the mail query out !